# UIScrollView not showing inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uistackview

I have one UIStackView that stacks vertically two horizontal UIStackViews. That worked just fine. But the first sub-UIStackView had too many elements so I decided to wrap it inside a scrollView. The problem is that when I do so, this first sub-view just disappears, as if the UIScrollView had a height of 0.

Here's the code:

```
func initViews(){
    let containerStack = UIStackView()
    addSubview(containerStack)
    containerStack.axis = .vertical
    containerStack.distribution = .equalCentering
    containerStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    containerStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let scrolledStack = UIStackView()
    containerStack.addArrangedSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(scrolledStack)
    scrolledStack.distribution = .fill
    scrolledStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    scrolledStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 30, bottom: 20, right: 30)
    
    scrolledStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrolledStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrolledStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrolledStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    scrolledStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    
    let otherStack = UIStackView()
    containerStack.addArrangedSubview(otherStack)
    otherStack.distribution = .equalCentering
    otherStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    otherStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30)
    
    
    containerStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    containerStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    containerStack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    containerStack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    
    
    for number in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]{
        let text = UITextView()
        text.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        text.text = number
        text.isScrollEnabled = false
        text.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        scrolledStack.addArrangedSubview(text)
    }
    for number in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]{
        let text = UITextView()
        text.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        text.text = number
        text.isScrollEnabled = false
        text.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        otherStack.addArrangedSubview(text)
    }
}
```

otherStack behaves as expected, but scrollView and scrolledStack just don't appear. If I remove the scrollView and just add scrolledStack to containerStack, both stacks appear as expected.

Comment: I think you are missing `scrolledStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: And you might also need to `scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrolledStack.centerXAnchor)` and `scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrolledStack.centerYAnchor)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many UI view elements - such as `UIScrollView` - have no intrinsic height.

You are putting a scroll view in a vertical stack view, with your stack view set to:

```
containerStack.distribution = .equalCentering
```

The problem comes in because the stack view cannot center its arranged subviews if they have no height.

If you change your `containerStack` to:

```
containerStack.distribution = .fillEqually
```

You will see both of the arranged subviews.

If you don't want them to have equal heights, then you need to provide ***some*** height value... either with an explicit `scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true` or perhaps relative to the overall height.

---

**Edit** - in response to comment...

Add these lines at the bottom of your `initViews()` func:

```
scrolledStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
scrolledStack.backgroundColor = .lightGray
otherStack.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
containerStack.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
```

and, instead of `.clear`, give your first set of text views:

```
text.backgroundColor = .cyan
```

and your second set of text views:

```
text.backgroundColor = .green
```

Here's how it looks now when I run your code:

[image]

That is probably *not* what you're going for, but by giving your views contrasting background colors, it makes it ***much*** easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! With this solution, my scrollView is finally visible, but not its subview scrolledStack or its content

Comment: @JOSEMAFUEN - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: I had to add `scrolledStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`  does it make sense?

Comment: I also removed `scrolledStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true` to allow it to scroll horizontally and added `scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:scrolledStack.heightAnchor).isActive = true` to make it adjust its content height

Answer (score 0):

I readapted a bit your code and created this swift playground:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let containerStack = UIStackView()
    view.addSubview(containerStack)
    containerStack.axis = .vertical
    containerStack.distribution = .equalCentering
    containerStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let scrolledStack = UIStackView()
    scrolledStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerStack.addArrangedSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(scrolledStack)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      scrolledStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
      scrolledStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
      scrolledStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
      scrolledStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
      scrolledStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor)
    ])

    let otherStack = UIStackView()
    containerStack.addArrangedSubview(otherStack)
    otherStack.distribution = .equalCentering
    otherStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    otherStack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 30)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      containerStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      containerStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
      containerStack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
      containerStack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    ])

    for number in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]{
      let text = UILabel()
      text.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
      text.text = number

      scrolledStack.addArrangedSubview(text)
      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        text.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
      ])
    }
    for number in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]{
      let text = UILabel()
      text.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
      text.text = number

      otherStack.addArrangedSubview(text)
    }

  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```